# Identifying results by group and rank using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping, window-functions

I have a table with the following structure:

```
id          timestamp       area
717416915   18:30:53.063    25.691601
717416915   18:31:34.863    31.200506
717416915   18:32:23.665    25.690088
1994018321  18:32:45.467    37.409171
1994018321  18:33:19.612    37.409171
424164505   18:36:16.634    18.22091
424164505   18:36:36.899    18.210754
424164505   18:37:08.614    19.829266
2394018356  18:37:27.231    79.31705
```

What I want to do is to summarize the values in such a way that I can identify the area per `id`, ordered by `timestamp`. For example if I wanted the first `area` value it would be the following:

```
id          timestamp       area_1
717416915   18:30:53.063    25.691601
1994018321  18:32:45.467    37.409171
424164505   18:36:16.634    18.22091
2394018356  18:37:27.231    79.31705
```

And if I wanted to get the second `area` value per `id` it would be the following:

```
id          timestamp       area_2
717416915   18:31:34.863    31.200506
1994018321  18:33:19.612    37.409171
424164505   18:36:36.899    18.210754
```

I understand that I need to sort by time, and then identify the first value per `id`. I don't quite understand how to do this. What I have tried doing is the following (which is not running, as I am still a little unclear on how to use the `OVER` function).

```
WITH T AS (
    SELECT * OVER(PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY a.timestamp) AS rnk
    FROM mytable AS a
) 
SELECT area as area_1
FROM T
WHERE rnk = 1
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.timestamp;
```

I was planning to use `rnk=2` etc, to get subsequent area values per `id`.

Comment: There is no record with `id=2394018356`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax should be as follows:

```
SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY a.timestamp) AS rnk
```

Answer (score 4):

With unique timestamp values, [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) does the same as [`rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html), a bit faster:

```sql
WITH t AS (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   ) 
SELECT id, ts, area AS area1
FROM   t
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER  BY id, ts;
```

There is a shorter way:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
       id
     , nth_value(ts  , 1) OVER w  AS ts
     , nth_value(area, 1) OVER w  AS area_n
FROM   tbl
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts);
```

Should perform similarly.

`nth_value(ts, 1)` is really just a noisy way of saying `first_value(ts)`, but you can also `nth_value(ts, 2)` etc, like you pondered.

Comment: Thanks Erwin - I was unaware of the window function.